# Anybody using SQL Server Spatial in a production environment?

Tags: sql-server, gis

I'm looking for some spatial database features but can't upgrade to SQL Server 2008 at the moment.  I've come across this open source [mssqlspatial](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=MsSqlSpatial&title=Features) package which would provide most of the features I need however I'm hesitant to deploy it without knowing if it's production ready.  I was wondering if anybody out there had deployed this package.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never heard of mssqlspatial, sorry. Have you considered [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/) though? That'll give you an open source spatial database, and I believe it's quite [well regarded](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/casestudies). Never used it myself.

Comment: PostGIS is really great, we just converted most of our data to it from SHP files. It's quiet impressive

Answer (score 0):

This isn't answer...just some additional info.

We just went to SQL Server 2008, but PostGIS would have been my first choice (wasn't my choice).  As MarkJ says, it is well regarded.

You might want to checkout SharpmapV2.  It's not a spatial database but you've got providers on just about everything including MsSqlSpatial:
http://sharpmapv2.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/SharpMap.Data.Providers/

And I'm seeing the same developers in both repositories (John Diss looks like a busy guy), so I think SharpMapv2 is more current:
http://mssqlspatial.codeplex.com/SourceControl/ListDownloadableCommits.aspx